# Apache camel configuration

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly

I use apache camel-cdi and wildfly 8.2. How to configurate thread pool for camel?
In documentation I only see config for spring, but I use java ee with wildfly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Java DSL configuration to [create a thread pool in Camel](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Apache_Camel_Development_Guide/BasicPrinciples-Thread.html).

> ```
> import org.apache.camel.spi.ExecutorServiceManager;
> import org.apache.camel.spi.ThreadPoolProfile;
> ExecutorServiceManager manager = context.getExecutorServiceManager();
> ThreadPoolProfile defaultProfile = manager.getDefaultThreadPoolProfile();
>  // Now, customize the profile settings.
> defaultProfile.setPoolSize(SomeSize);
> defaultProfile.setMaxQueueSize(QueueSize);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your use case but you can definitely use thread pooling with Camel Java DSL. The format would be something like the below:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming().executorService(threadPool)
```

Individual components can also allow for individual threading (see file2 for example). If you have the Camel in Action book, chapter 10 is all about concurrency. It goes into threading and concurrency in much more detail.

Comment: where I can configurate pool size for camel?

Comment: It's in the snippet above, the 20 in Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20); is the number of threads.

Comment: Are you crazy, I have hundreds of long routes. I need to configurate default pool